# Paperclip- need to generate migration on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip

I have Paperclip (and AWS) working on my Rails app locally to upload/save avatars. However, when I deploy I am getting this error `model missing required attr_accessor for 'image_file_name'`. I noticed my local table does have the additional Paperclip columns of `image_file_name`, `image_content_type`, `image_file_size`, `image_updated_at`, but my Heroku db does not have these additional columns.

Does this mean I need to generate another migration for the deployed (Heroku) tables? Would it be just like how I did for local...running `rails generate Paperclip <table> image`? Or how would I do that on Heroku?

Comment: have you done `heroku run rake db:migrate --app YOUR_APP_NAME`?

Comment: That's what I was asking - thanks!!